# How to Convert Bitmap to "YUV_420_888" format?

Tags: java, android, google-mlkit

I have a bitmap and i want to process this bitmap with ML-kit face recognition. When I give this bitmap directly to ML kit i see this message : "StreamingFormatChecker: ML Kit has detected that you seem to pass camera frames to the detector as a Bitmap object. This is inefficient. Please use YUV_420_888 format for camera2 API or NV21 format for (legacy) camera API and directly pass down the byte array to ML Kit."

So my question is how can I convert a bitmap to "YUV_420_888" format?

Comment: Converting the bitmap does not make it more efficient. Instead, if possible directly get the image in one of these formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [InputImage.fromBitmap](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/InputImage#fromBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int)) method and pass the result into the API you want to call.